# How to debug Google map Oops! Something went wrong on Android?

Tags: javascript, android, google-maps, reverse-geocoding

Not sure why, but I get "Oops! Something went wrong" on Android devices...

The map does show for half a second and then get that Oops message with the gray background.

How can I debug or see what is causing it...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I was trying to limit the access just to the IP address of my server and my home IP,

Google has an option in the API manager -> Credentials -> Server API key ->
Accept requests from these server IP addresses (Optional)

Examples: 192.168.0.1, 172.16.0.0/12, 2001:db8::1 or 2001:db8::/64

When adding my server and home IP address it becomes blocked and the map is showing the Opps gray background message... once removed it works fine from anywhere...

I would love to know how to restrict the IP address just for my server though...